# Reading and storing xml data in python variables

Tags: python-2.7, xml-parsing

I have an XML like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Server>
  <name>johny</name> 
  <address>statestreet</address>
  <city>Hyderabad</city> 
</Server>
```

I need to store each attribute in separate variable in code.So i am writing code like this

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
tree=et.parse('sample.xml')  
root=tree.getroot()
for i in root.findall('Server'):
    name=i.find('name').text
    address = i.find('address').text
    city = i.find('city').text
```

But it is not storing anything.Please help me

Comment: How are you storing the data after getting them from `xml`? How do you want to sort it?

Comment: I am storing it in every signle variableas mentioned in the below solution.Now i wana store it in the form of dictionary.Please help me in this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
def xmldata():
    config_xml = et.parse('sample.xml')
    root = sample.getroot()
    result = {}
    for child in root.getchildren():
        if child.tag=='name':
            result['name'] =child.text
        if child.tag=='address':
            result['address'] =child.text
        if child.tag=='city':
            result['city'] =child.text

    return result
```

And you will get: `{'name':'johny','address':'statestreet','city':'hyderabad'}` back

Answer (score 0):

i got a solution.I have written a function :

```
def xmldata():
    config_xml = et.parse('sample.xml')
    root = sample.getroot()
    for child in root.getchildren():
        if child.tag=='name':
            name =child.text
        if child.tag=='address':
            address =child.text
        if child.tag=='city':
            city =child.text

    return name,address,city
```

but when i call this def in the main function,it is in the form of list`('johny','statestreet','hyderabad')`.How can i get it in the form of dictionary `(name:'johny',address:'statestreet',city:'hyderabad')`